# php int max not being converted to floating point

Tags: php

The php [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) states:

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it
> will be interpreted as a float instead.

So I determined the integer max size

`echo PHP_INT_MAX;`

and got 2147483647.

I tested this statement out with

`echo PHP_INT_MAX + PHP_INT_MAX;`

and got 4294967294.

Shouldn't this be a float since I went beyond the max in integers?

Comment: You need to be a little more specific about your platform, PHP version, etc. For me this piece of code returns `1.844674407371E+19` (PHP 5.4.17, OSX 10.9, 64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're echo'ing the result so, it's already cast to a string.

This might help:

```
$result = PHP_INT_MAX;

echo gettype($result); // prints "integer"

$result2 = $result + $result;

echo gettype($result2); // prints "double"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a *double*, which is more precise than a single precision number (a float). This can be verified:

```
echo gettype(PHP_INT_MAX + PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Echoes: `double`

Comment: Why would it make sense for an integer language constant to ever be a `double`?